# Structuring mongoose callbacks in an async.waterfall method.

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

The first function in my `async waterfall` is one that takes an `_id` as input and uses the `findOne()` method to get two attributes from the document with that particular `_id`. I then pass these two attributes in a `callback` to the next function in the waterfall. Here is the non-working code:

```
async.waterfall([
      function (callback) {
        Results.findOne({ _id:match_id }, function (result) {
          var match_date = result.match_date;
          var match_week = result.week;
          });
          callback(match_date, match_week);
      },
        function (match_date, match_week) {
        // ...
        // do something with the date and week ...
```

I see the problem is that the `callback` is getting called while the `findOne` method is still executing, hence the variables are undefined and the process crashes.

I understand that I need to structure the code so that the `callback` is called only when mongoose finishes querying the database, however I'm not sure how to do this and have read every relevant post here and still can't get my head around it.

Any help would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should do it inside mongoose callback:

```
async.waterfall([
      function (callback) {
            Results.findOne({_id:match_id}, function(result) {
                  ...
                  callback(match_date, match_week);
            });
      },
      ...
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This doesn't work though. That callback is from the `async.waterfall` method and is what gets passed to the next function in the waterfall. I need a callback for the `findOne` method.

Comment: @duketon your callback of findOne is second parameter of function